About the variety structure of the Severi variety
I'm currently studying the Severi variety of (parameterizations of) rational curves of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^n$ with multiple kinds of stratification (by genus, properties on singularities, etc). But I have a basic question: I don't really get the structure of variety that the space
$$
M_d^n = \{f\colon \mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^n \;\vert\; f \text{ is of degree } d\}
$$ of parameterizations has. It seems that you can get fancy and talk about Hilbert schemes, etc. but I wanted a more basic approach (staying on varieties and not going to schemes).
I've read that $M_d^n$ can be identified with an open subset of $\mathbb G(d,n)$, and I can see that that each $f$ is prescribed by $n+1$ sections
$$
f_0, \ldots, f_n \in H^0(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(d), \mathbb P ^1),
$$ so we have $d+1$ coefficients for each $f_i$, and $(n+1)(d+1)$ coefficients to specify a map $\mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^n$. Furthermore, two maps agree everywhere iff their defining coordinates are multiples, i.e.
$$
f_i = \alpha g_i\; \forall 0\le i\le n
$$
so the "projective" part goes here. But I can't see how the very relevant condition of
$$
\not\exists p\in\mathbb P^1: f_0(p) = \ldots = f_n(p) = 0
$$ to make a map to projective spaces can be translated in terms of the coefficients (this seems like an open condition on coefficients, so $M_d^n$ would be naturally identified as an open subset of some projective space).
Approaches using linear systems of divisors/arguments about invertible sheaves also seem to have a connection with this, but I can't seem to grasp how to make this step. In summary, I want to know a natural (but not too abstract way) to give this moduli space a proper structure as a variety. Any help is appreciated!
Edit: It’s not hard to prove that the subset of subspaces of $S_d = H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(d))$ of dimension $n+1$ in which, for some base, all of the homogeneous polynomials that make this base have some common root $p\in \mathbb P^1$ is open (in $\mathbb G(n+1, S_d)$). You can in fact prove this using resultants. The thing is that $M^n_d$ would now correspond to the frame bundle associated to the canonical bundle of the Grassmannian, and I can’t see what would be the analogous concept/structure in algebraic geometry.

I think that resultants might be of use here.

Have you flipped through GTM 187 ? I don't have it handy but I think it addresses this.

@DerekAllums yeah! Trying to wrap my head around the main things there. Harris also published "On the Severi variety" which is somewhat helpful, so I'm trying to read it

As stated in my own question, there's a fancy description of $M_d^n$ using the Hilbert scheme, but I don't quite grasp the idea yet. For this reason, I managed to make a classical construction.
First of all, my definition of $M_d^n$ was incorrect. One also requires that the curves in $M_d^n$ are nondegenerate; i.e. there's no hyperplane in $\mathbb P^n$ that contains it. With $k$ algebraically closed (or even infinite), this amounts to require that the sections are linearly independent.
Identify $S_d := \Gamma(\mathcal O(d), \mathbb P^1)$ with $k^{d+1}$ as vector spaces (using the obvious map $s^i t^{d-i} \mapsto e_i$); then the set of $n$-tuples of regular functions that are linearly independent is in bijection with the set of $(d+1)\times (n+1)$ matrices (whose lines correspond to the coefficients of the sections) and that no maximal minor vanishes. So this is an open set in the space of $(d+1)\times(n+1)$ matrices with the usual affine topology; this is very similar to the construction of the Grassmannian as a space of matrices, and give the frame bundle idea described in the question.
Furthermore, we require that the sections do not vanish simultaneously, which amounts to not vanishing in the affine patches $U_0 = \{t \ne 0\}$ and $U_1 = \{s \ne 0\}$. So the dehomogenized polynomials in one variable cannot have a common root, and having a root (since $k$ is alg. closed.) is a closed condition using resultants. So if we take the intersection $V$ of these two opens $V_i$, we have a bijection between $V$ and $n$-tuples of linearly independent sections with no common zero.
This almost gives us a construction of $M_d^n$, except for the fact that two maps $\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^n$ prescribed by coordinates agree iff their coordinates are nonzero scalar multiples of each other (by the same scalar). Clearly $\mathbf{0} \not\in V$, so if we take $\mathbb P(V) \subseteq \mathbb P\left(\mathcal M_{(d+1)\times(n+1)}\right)$, we have a bijection between $M_d^n$ and $\mathbb P(V)$ through
$$
\begin{align*}
    {M_d^n} \quad\quad &\longleftrightarrow \quad \quad {\mathbb P(V)} \\
    {(f_0:\cdots:f_n)} &\longmapsto {\begin{bmatrix}
    \textbf{---} & f_0 & \textbf{---}\\
    \textbf{---} & \vdots & \textbf{---}\\
    \textbf{---} & f_n & \textbf{---}
    \end{bmatrix}_\sim}.
\end{align*}$$
and we might define its structure through this map.

Remark: When considering the affine patches to apply the resultant, it's clear that the choice of patch simply changes the order of the coefficients considered when building the determinant. Maybe those are equivalent (i.e. $V_0 = V_1$) - there are homogeneous versions of the resultant, but I didn't put work to learn about it.
